# Next Button doesn't work in my Swift quiz app

Tags: arrays, swift

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5D59p.png)This is a popular practice quiz app that I also tried to make. I placed the array QlistsA in a separate file. To communicate with it is still challenging to me. Everything worked, but I'm now stuck to go to next question by pushing the next button. The next button function is not working, but crushes. Any idea where I made an error? Really appreciate it! (In the screenshot, I haven't made the label "Score" yet. Disregard. I hope I can make it later.)

```
import UIKit

struct Question {
var question: String!
var answerList: [String] = []
var answerNum: Int!
} 

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var qNum: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var question: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var aButtons: [UIButton]!
@IBOutlet weak var smileLabel1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var smileLabel2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!


var qlists = [Question]()
var qNumber = Int()
var answerNum = Int()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    qlists = qlistsA

    PickQuiz()
    Hide()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Just set a initial view.
func PickQuiz() {

        question.text = qlists[0].question
        answerNum = qlists[0].answerNum

            for i in 0..<aButtons.count{
            aButtons[i].setTitle(qlists[0].answerList[i], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
}

    func Hide(){
    smileLabel1.hidden = true
    smileLabel2.hidden = true
}


@IBAction func answer1(sender: AnyObject) {
    if answerNum == 0 {
        smileLabel1.hidden = false
        smileLabel2.hidden = true
        smileLabel1.text = ":)"

    } else {
        smileLabel2.hidden = true
        smileLabel1.hidden = false
        smileLabel1.text = ":("

    }
}

@IBAction func answer2(sender: AnyObject) {
     if answerNum == 1 {
        smileLabel1.hidden = true
        smileLabel2.hidden = false
        smileLabel2.text = ":)"

    }
    else {
        smileLabel1.hidden = true
        smileLabel2.hidden = false
        smileLabel2.text = ":("
    }

    }

@IBAction func gotoNext(sender: AnyObject) {

    Hide()

    for qNumber = 1; qNumber < qlists.count; qNumber++ {
        question.text = qlists[qNumber].question
        answerNum = qlists[qNumber].answerNum
        print("The loop were excuted \(qNumber) times") // The loop is working, but the labels display only the last entries.

        for i in 0..<aButtons.count{
            aButtons[i].setTitle(qlists[qNumber].answerList[i], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }

    }

}

}
```

The array is as follows:

```
import Foundation

var qlistsA = [
Question(
    question: "1. What is 10 times 2?",
    answerList: ["20", "12"],
    answerNum: 0
),

Question(
    question: "2. What is 13 mod 5?",
    answerList: ["5", "3"],
    answerNum: 1
),

Question(
    question: "3. Do you like UMBC?",
    answerList: ["Yes", "No"],
    answerNum: 0
)
```

]

Comment: i think you should debug to see where it crashed

Comment: I discovered that the gotoNext button had a referencing problem. :( It's cleared and I am a middle of improvement. I think I shouldn't use PickQuiz() in func of the gotoNext button. I'm making a loop there, but I'm still newbie. The labels only shows the last element of the array. I will update. Thanks for your comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably the QlistsA. What is it? A class or a global array? It has to be initialzed and I don't se you do that any where in this code.
So you are setting you qlists to a nil value and then you try to access it and the app crashes.
You can debug it and set a break point just after the qlists = QlistsA  and see it it really is nil.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I updated the one I worked since last night. Now I don't know how to display data click by click. (I'm not quite happy about the code, but that's been around on the Internet. So I've been trying to improve for my assignment. This quiz format is exactly what I need, but couldn't find without paying $100 or so.)